# How to display standard yii stacktrace?

Tags: php, exception, yii, stack-trace

```
'errorHandler' => array(
        'class' => 'ErrorHandler',
        'errorAction' => 'page/find',
    ),
```

http://shot.qip.ru/008pAk-4IA4wMhU6/

I have standard error handling with beautiful error page. But for develop environment I need standard stacktrace on it below.

Examlpe: http://shot.qip.ru/008pAk-4IA4wMhU7/

If I comment 'errorAction' I can see just standart stacktrace, in other case I cant display this stacktrace.

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
                    'categories' => 'application, exception.*',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, profile, info',
                    'showInFireBug' => true,
                    'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
                ),
                array(
                    'class'=>'ext.yii-debug-toolbar.YiiDebugToolbarRoute',
                    'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','192.168.0.100'),
                ),
                array(
                    'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
                    'report'=>'summary',
                    // Shows the execution time of each labeled with a code block.
                    // The value of "report" can also be specified as a "callstack".
                ),

            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Error handler by default uses two types of views for 
  Production named as error.php;
  Development named as named as exception.php;

Based on your routing and error handler code. I see you have defined a custom error action
You will have to place your custom Errors views in either of the following folders, in the format specified in the link below and use the standard error action.

```
themes/ThemeName/views/system: when a theme is active.
protected/views/system
```

See this Documentation for detailed explanation
Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler

Comment: Posted my log routes above

Comment: See my revised answer, and do edit your question instead of adding info as an answer, it will help people with similar doubts, thanks, and hope my explanation helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this extenstion http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/

> The Yii Debug Toolbar is a configurable set of panels that display various debug information about the current request/response and when clicked, display more details about the panel's content.
>   It is a ported to PHP famous Django Debug Toolbar.